# Function operates only under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm mostly just looking for someone to point me in the correct direction of what I should research, I'm pretty new to jQuery and JavaScript.

How can I have a jQuery event listener operate only once under certain conditions? When I use if else statements, as soon as the `if` argument is met once, the event listener remains indefinitely. For example:

```
 function stateAction(editVal) {
    if (editVal == 'first') {
        $('#btn-1').click(function () {
           alert('First');
           })
    } else if (editVal == 'second') {
        $('#btn-2').click(function () {
           alert('Second');
           })
    }
};

$('#ul-dropdown').on('click', '.markup', function () {
    var editingState = $(this).attr('id');
    stateAction(editingState);
});
```

With this function, if `'first'` is ever passed into `stateAction`, then clicking `#btn-1` will continue to alert `'First'`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: javascript can't predict when you no longer want an event listener in place, you have to remove it yourself - hint: `.off`

Comment: You can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) here is an example `$('#btn-1').one("click", function () {
           alert('First');
           })`

Comment: Thanks all! Good to hear from you @Titus

Answer (score 0):

You could have the events unbind them selves once they execute.

Add $("#btn-1").off("click") and $("#btn-2").off("click") to the click functions respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure what you're trying to do
 you can always check the [.one() method](http://api.jquery.com/one/)
Hope this will help you.
SYA :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the variable in the click handlers.

```
$("#btn-1").click(function() {
    if (editVal == "first") {
        alert("First");
    }
});
$("#btn-2").click(function() {
    if (editVal == "second") {
        alert("Second");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Up to all comments and answers you can use `.one()` .. But I'm little bit wonder why you trying to make your code like this .. while you can simply use it like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var editVal = '';  //make it global
   // btn 1 click event
   $('#btn-1').click(function () {
      if(editVal == 'first'){alert('First')};
   });
   // btn 2 click event
   $('#btn-2').click(function () {
      if(editVal == 'second'){alert('Second')};
   });
   $('#ul-dropdown').on('click', '.markup', function () {
      editVal = $(this).attr('id').toLowerCase().trim();
   });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var editVal = '';  //make it global
   // btn 1 click event
   $('#btn-1').click(function () {
      if(editVal == 'first'){alert('First')};
   });
   // btn 2 click event
   $('#btn-2').click(function () {
      if(editVal == 'second'){alert('Second')};
   });
   $('.markup').on('click', function () {
      editVal = $(this).attr('id').toLowerCase().trim();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-1">Btn 1</button>
<button id="btn-2">Btn 2</button>

<a class="markup" id="first">Click Btn 1</a>
<a class="markup" id="second">Click Btn 2</a>
```